# Are there a constants in scapy for TCP and UDP?

Tags: constants, scapy

Are there a constants in scapy for TCP and UDP?

I mean

```
TCP=6, UDP=17
```

etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**a)** 
looking up the [implementation](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/layers/inet.py#L337) for `IP` we see that `IP.proto` is a `ByteEnumField("proto", 0, IP_PROTOS),`. This means, it takes values from the `IP_PROTOS` list which just loads your os `/etc/protocols/`. So you could either parse `/etc/protocols` yourself or, of scapy is already loaded, access the `IP_PROTOS` object directly:

```
>>> IP_PROTOS
</etc/protocols/ pim ip ax_25 esp tcp ah mpls_in_ip rohc ipv6_opts xtp st mobility_header dccp igmp ipv6_route igp ddp etherip wesp xns_idp ipv6_frag vrrp gre ipcomp encap ipv6 iso_tp4 sctp ipencap rsvp hip udp ggp hmp idpr_cmtp hopopt fc skip icmp pup manet isis rdp l2tp ipv6_icmp udplite egp ipip ipv6_nonxt eigrp idrp shim6 rspf ospf vmtp>
>>> IP_PROTOS.tcp
6
>>> IP_PROTOS.udp
17
>>> IP_PROTOS.ip
0
```

**b)** An alternative approach would be to read scapys layer binding information directly. This is the information that is added to a layer when you (or scapy core itself) calls `bind_layers(lower,upper[,overload_fields])`. You can easily read that information as follows:

```
>>> TCP.overload_fields
{<class 'scapy.layers.inet6.IPv6'>: {'nh': 6}, <class 'scapy.layers.inet.IP'>: {'frag': 0, 'proto': 6}}
```

Means, in case TCP is a payload to IPv4 (`scapy.layers.inet.IP`) it will override `IP.proto=6`.
Here's that same information for UDP

```
>>> UDP.overload_fields
{<class 'scapy.layers.inet6.IPv6'>: {'nh': 17}, <class 'scapy.layers.inet.IP'>: {'frag': 0, 'proto': 17}}
```

For reference, [here is the bind_layers call for TCP/UDP](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/layers/inet.py#L730)

Answer (score 0):

TCP and UDP are the initiators of TCP/UDP packets.
For example:

```
pack = IP(dst="www.google.com") / UDP(dport=80)
pack.show()
```

Result:

```
>>> pack = IP(dst="www.google.com") / UDP(dport=80)
>>> pack.show()

###[ IP ]###
  version= 4
  ihl= None
  tos= 0x0
  len= None
  id= 1
  flags= 
  frag= 0
  ttl= 64
  proto= udp
  chksum= None
  src= 'Your local address'
  dst= Net('www.google.com')
  \options\
###[ UDP ]###
     sport= domain
     dport= http
     len= None
     chksum= None
>>>
```

Comment: not what I meant, I asked about constants. For example PROTOCOL_TCP will equal 6 and PROTOCOL_UDP will equal 17. I mean enums